# Going through user input and multi-dimensional arrays in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, for-loop, input

I am trying to make a code where a user has 5 tries to guess a number and if any of the 3 series of numbers within `Winning_order` then both of the for loops will break. The `usersInputs` stores the users inputs to be compared with `Winning_order`. So for example, if the number `1,2,3` or `1,2,4,5,3`  is inputted by the user the loop will print `There is a Correlation` and the for loops will stop. If the input is `7,8,9,3,2` since no 3 numbers are present within the `Winning_order` the loops will just stop. There is a problem with the `match_arrays` function and I do not know how to go about stopping the nested for loops if the `if statement` is valid.

Checking if the function has a correlation

```
int match_arrays(int *arr1, int *arr2, int len) {
  for (int p = 0; p < len; p++) {
    if (arr1[p] != arr2[p]) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

main() function

```
int main(void)
{
    int Winning_order[3][3] = {{1,2,3}, {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}};
    int input = 0;
    int usersInputs[5] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
           printf("\nPlayer input: ");

           scanf("%d", &input);
           usersInputs[i] = input;
           for (int p = 0; p < 5; p++) {
                if (match_arrays(usersInputs, Winning_order[p], 3)) {printf("There's a Corelation");}
    }}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please use a more orthodox indentation style for C code.  It is hard to read your layout. Multiple close braces on a single line is a no-no; multiple consecutive close braces at the same indent level is another (not shown).

Comment: `Winning_order[p]` that can't be right. `p` goes up to `4` whereas only `0, 1, 2` are valid indices for `Winning_order`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways of approaching breaking a double loop (or to generalize: a nested loop), this solution is not the optimal, the best, or the recommended, but it works. I fixed the indentation and some naming issues, but I won't fix anything else.

This is a working snippet:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int match_arrays(int *arr1, int *arr2, int len) {
  for (int p = 0; p < len; p++) {
    if (arr1[p] != arr2[p]) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}

int main(void) {
  int winning_order[3][3] = {{1,2,3}, {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}};
  int input = 0;
  int users_inputs[5] = {0};
  for (int i, break_i = 0; !break_i && i < 5; i++){
    printf("\nPlayer input: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    users_inputs[i] = input;
    for (int p = 0; p < 3; p++) {
      if (match_arrays(users_inputs, winning_order[p], 3)) {
        printf("There's a Corelation\n");
        break_i = 1;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I made this easy for you to understand. I added a new `flag` to the outer `for` loop called `break_i` with an initial falsy value. Simultaneously, I added a short circuit `&&` operation to the `for` loop.

Inside your inner loop, I added a `break_i = 1` statement that will make the outer loop stop. Immediately after that, I use the `break` statement to break the inner loop.

---

P.S.: I also fixed the index out of bounds pointed out by @kaylum. You may want to use a macro or `sizeof()` next time, but that's beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: Thanks for the code that breaks the for loops however the numbers `2,5,8` and  `1,2,4,5,3` does not work. The for loop breaks work well, thanks for that

Comment: That's not part of your question, so I didn't answer it. As stated above, I won't be fixing anything beyond the nested loop break :)